# Logback's debug output not shown

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, logging, logback

I'm running a Java servlet inside [Tomcat 7.0.52](https://tomcat.apache.org/).

This is my *logback.xml* file

```
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/home/my-user/my-log.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Unfortunately I'm nowhere seeing [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)'s debug output. Neither in `catalina.out`, nor in *my-log.log* or on the console. Where is it?

Just to add: Changes in *logback.xml* are reflected in the logging output.

Comment: `catalina.out` is the redirection of stdout/stderr, and you don't have a console appender in your logback configuration; that is one of your problems.

Comment: @fge Convert your comment to an answer, you've been right. :-)

Comment: Uh, that doesn't explain why you don't get anything in your logfile though

Comment: @fge Sorry, that was a misunderstanding. I was getting something in my log file, but not the debug output of Logback itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your logback configuration, you define a file appender. What you do *not* do is define a [`ConsoleAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/ConsoleAppender.html), which will log to stdout/stderr.

`catalina.out` being the redirection of stdout/stderr used by the Tomcat init script, adding this to your configuration should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>debug</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern><![CDATA[
            %-20(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) %-5level %logger{80}[%L] - %msg%n
      ]]></pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/home/my-user/my-log.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```